# Как сделать переход на фрагмент в spinner'e со строчки во фрагменте

Tags: android-fragment, adapter, android-spinner, transaction, fragment-transaction

MainActivity
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Fragment fragment = new FragmentOne();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

}
```

Fragment1
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

```
Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
FragmentTwo fragmentTwo;
FragmentFree fragmentFree;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    {

        VideoView videoPlayer;
        videoPlayer = vista.findViewById(R.id.videoView3);
        Uri myVideoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + R.raw.video);
        videoPlayer.setVideoURI(myVideoUri);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(requireContext());
        videoPlayer.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoPlayer);
    }

    fragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo();
    fragmentFree = new FragmentFree();

    spinner1 = vista.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    String selected = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            requireContext(), R.layout.custom_spinner, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.List)

    );
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.customs_spinner_dropdown);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner2 = vista.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    String selected1 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), selected1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            requireContext(), R.layout.custom_spinner, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ListTwo)
    );
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.customs_spinner_dropdown);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter1);

    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    selectFragment(fragmentTwo);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    selectFragment(fragmentFree);
                    break;
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    return vista;
}

private void selectFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FragOne,fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
}
```

Разметка фрагмент 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/FragOne"
tools:context=".FragmentOne">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Relative1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="235dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/big" />

</RelativeLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/Relative1"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:background="#1dbf48">

    <TableRow

        android:id="@+id/first_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1dbf48">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_setting"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:text="@string/Glav"
            android:textAlignment="center" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button24"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_setting"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:text="@string/Fhoto"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_setting"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:text="@string/Info"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_setting"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:text="@string/Contacts"
            android:textAlignment="center" />


    </TableRow>

    <TableRow


        android:id="@+id/second_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:background="#1dbf48">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_setting"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:text="@string/News"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_setting"
            android:entries="@array/List"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_setting"
            android:entries="@array/ListTwo"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:textAlignment="center" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_setting"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:text="@string/Me"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

    </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

   <VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView3"
    android:layout_width="412dp"
    android:layout_height="656dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Relative1"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="-1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-328dp" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда на спиннер1 нажимаю, выпадает список, при нажатие на первый элемент списка, появляется фрагмент 2, но поверх фрагмента 1, а нужнен чистый лист фрагмента 2

Comment: Вроде всë верно. Кроме кажется ИД контейнера фрагментов. Он должен быть тот что в активист, где текущий фрагмент отображается

Comment: в активити айди container,  private void selectFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } вот делаю транзакцию, в итоге как вы писали не получается, getFragment перечеркнут , а fragment подчеркивает красным

Comment: Я уже запутался( Кажется, код в комментарии и код в вопросе не совпадают. Вам, наверное, надо из фрагмента А заменить в активити фрагмент А в контейнере активити на фрагмент Б. В этом случае должно сработать что-то типа такого кода: `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, FagmentB()).commit()`

Comment: нужно из спинера, который находится в фрагменте, заменить строчку на новый фрагмент, ваш вариант просто откроет новый фрагмент при старте

Comment: Мне всё ещё не всё понятно) Что значит, например, `заменить строчку на новый фрагмент`? Я всё ещё воспринимаю вашу задачу как 1. В активити фрагмент А. 2. В А есть спинер. 3. При выборе элемента спинера надо открыть фрагмент Б вместо фрагмента А.

Comment: разобрался, меняет все правильно, но фрагмент лежит на фрагменте, при выборе строки меняет фрагмент, но он ложится на старый

Comment: Разве не это вам было нужно? Положить один фрагмент поверх другого? Если надо чтобы они рядом на экране отображались (например фрагмент со спиннером сверху, а под ним меяются 2 других фрагмента), то надо в активити 2 контейнера для фрагментов - один для того что со спиннером, а второй - для других.

Comment: его нужно заменить, а не положить на другой

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под `заменить, а не положить на другой`? `replace` в транзакции как раз заменяет фрагмент в контейнере. Попробуйте как-то так сформулировать свою задачу чтобы можно было её однозначно понять. И так же максимально подробно опишите что у вас сейчас получается. Приложите максимально актуальный код. Уберите из него всё лишнее. Например у вас, кажется, 2 спинера - возможно мы с вами о разных говорим. Очень сложно общаться не видя актуальный код и не владея терминологией общей.

Comment: Поменял, добавил фото, нужна чистая страница фрагмента

Comment: Всё ещё непонятно. Возможно, вы имеете в виду под "поверх" координатную ось `y` (т.е. направление сверху вниз на экране), а не координатную ось `z` (направление перпендикулярное плоскости экрана)? Что такое `чистая страница фрагмента` - непонятно.

Comment: Вот у меня первый фрагмент, разметку приложил, второй фрагмент, у меня с пустой разметкой, на первом фрагменте нажимаю на спиннер и на 1 элемент в списке, появляется второй фрагмент, но нужно чтобы первый фрагмент пропал, а остался только 2, не знаю как еще объяснить, нужно перевернуть страницу , как в книге))

Comment: Всё ещё непонятно) На картинке в вопросе - сколько фрагментов, какие они, где у них границы и где там спиннер?

Comment: на картинке фрагмент One, спиннер 2 кнопки-"наши лошади" и "услуги" когда нажимаю наши лошади, выпадает список, при нажатии на первый элемент в этом списке получаю фрагмет Two, при нажатии на 2-ой, фрагмент Free, но они отображаются  в этом же фрагменте, а цель, новая страница

Comment: Возможно, стало понятнее) Посмотрите мой коммент от 10.03 1704. Там я писал, что надо указывать ID контейнера активити. А вы в коде у себя указываете ID вьюхи внутри фрагмента. Я вообще не думал, что такое может в принципе сработать)

Comment: getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, FagmentB()).commit() в этом варианте Я сразу вылетаю на новый фрагмент

Comment: смотрите что получается,  switch (i) {
                    case 0:

                        break;
                    case 1:
                        selectFragment(fragmentTwo);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        selectFragment(fragmentFree);
                        break; когда в case 0 идет fragment Two, при запуске приложения я сразу выхожу на фрагмент 2 , но если его сместить в case 1, то при выборе в списке работает корректно, но тогда в списке 1 строку Я использовать не могу

Comment: Т.е. всё правильно работает? Кроме того, что у вас слушатель выбора элемента спиннера срабатывает при старте экрана?

Comment: Да, почти правильно))) как мне сделать теперь чтобы он срабатывал не при старте , а при выборе 1ой позиции в спинере?

Comment: Попробуйте вот это добавить перед назначением слушателя: `spinner1.setSelection(0,false)`